# Solving a system of equation by moment condition reports error but minimum distance works

Tags: r, distance, method-of-moments

I do not understand the following error message I get using the `gmm` function in `R`. The code below creates two moment conditions (one for observations denoted by `x` and another one for observations denoted by `y`).

```
  rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
  cat("\014")
  options(scipen=999) # no scientific notation

  set.seed(123)

  # == Set the parameters
  v1 = 10
  v2 = 20
  v3 = 30

  c1 = -2
  c2 = -3


  # == Set the data
  nx <- 20000
  x1 = runif(nx, min = 0, max = 1)
  x2 = runif(nx, min = 1, max = 2)
  x3 = runif(nx, min = 2, max = 3)
  x4 = runif(nx, min = 4, max = 5)
  x5 = runif(nx, min = 5, max = 6)

  xA = x1 * v1 + x2 * v2 + x3 * v3 + x4 * c1 + x5 * c2

  ny <- 20000
  y1 = runif(ny, min = 0, max = 10)
  y2 = runif(ny, min = 10, max = 20)
  y3 = runif(ny, min = 20, max = 30)
  y4 = runif(ny, min = 40, max = 50)
  y5 = runif(ny, min = 50, max = 60)

  yA = y1 * v1 + y2 * v2 + y3 * v3 + y4 * c1 + y5 * c2

  # == Set the moment

  x <- data.frame(d1 = x1, d2 = x2, d3 = x3, d4 = x4, d5 = x5, dA = xA)
  y <- data.frame(d1 = y1, d2 = y2, d3 = y3, d4 = y4, d5 = y5, dA = yA)

  dt <- rbind(x, y)

  gmm.fun <- function(tet, DATA){
    x1 = DATA$d1[1:nx]
    x2 = DATA$d2[1:nx]
    x3 = DATA$d3[1:nx]
    x4 = DATA$d4[1:nx]
    x5 = DATA$d5[1:nx]
    xA = DATA$dA[1:nx]

    y1 = DATA$d1[(nx+1):ny]
    y2 = DATA$d2[(nx+1):ny]
    y3 = DATA$d3[(nx+1):ny]
    y4 = DATA$d4[(nx+1):ny]
    y5 = DATA$d5[(nx+1):ny]
    yA = DATA$dA[(nx+1):ny]

    m1 =  x1 * tet[1] + x2 * tet[2] + x3 * tet[3] + x4 * tet[4] + x5 * tet[5] - xA
    m2 =  y1 * tet[1] + y2 * tet[2] + y3 * tet[3] + y4 * tet[4] + y5 * tet[5] - yA
    f <- cbind(m1, m2)
  #  print(f)
    return(f)
  }

  t0 <- c(v1, v2, v3, c1, c2)    # true values
  t0 <- runif(5)                 # random parameters
  require(gmm)
  res123 <- gmm(gmm.fun, x = dt, t0 = t0)
  summary(res123)
```

The error I get is:

```
Error in AA %*% t(X) : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
In addition: Warning message:
In ar.ols(x, aic = aic, order.max = order.max, na.action = na.action,  :
  model order:  1 singularities in the computation of the projection matrix 
  results are only valid up to model order 0
```

which refers to a singularity. However, I also solved the problem with a minimum distance estimator, and it turns out that I can recover the 5 parameters. Here is the `R` script.

```
min.dist.fun <- function(tet, DATA){

    y1 = DATA$d1
    y2 = DATA$d2
    y3 = DATA$d3
    y4 = DATA$d4
    y5 = DATA$d5
    yA = DATA$dA

    m =  (y1 * tet[1] + y2 * tet[2] + y3 * tet[3] + y4 * tet[4] + y5 * tet[5] - yA)^2
    ret= mean(m) 
    # print(f)
    return(ret)
  }



  require(nloptr)
  t0 <- c(v1, v2, v3, c1, c2)
  t0 <- runif(5)
  sol<-nloptr(x0 = t0,
              eval_f = min.dist.fun,
              # lb = c(0,0),
              # ub = c(.99,.99),
              opts = list("algorithm"="NLOPT_LN_BOBYQA",
                          ftol_rel = 1.e-7, ftol_abs = 1.e-9, 
                          xtol_rel = 1.e-7, xtol_abs = 0, 
                          maxeval = 1000), DATA = dt) 
  sol
```

So, I do not understand why the minimum distance works while the GMM approach does not.

Comment: You never use the value of `ret` in your definition of the objective function.

Comment: sorry, you are right. my problem is that the minimum distance estimator actually works, but the `gmm` does not.

Comment: Please, see that I modified question.

Comment: Because your question is about a runtime error, it would be better to post a modified version of it on [SO].  That site will insist you first simplify your code into a minimum reproducible example.